# The number of real roots of $(x+3)^4 + (x+5)^4 = 16$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I was solving some problems and I came across this question:

Q: The number of real roots of  $(x+3)^4 + (x+5)^4 = 16$ is

```
                            (a) 0            (b) 2
                            (c) 4            (d) none of these
```

Solution:     put $y = x + (3+5)/2 =  x+4$

```
    the equation becomes
```

=>  $(y-1)^4  + (y+1)^4  =  16$ ---- (i)
  => $2{y^4 + 6(y)^2 + 1 } =  16$ --------(ii)

My question is how was (i) converted to (ii)? I just couldn't get it. Please help?

Comment: Are $x$ and $X$ different or the same?

Comment: I have edited your question on the assumption that $x$ and $X$ both should be $x$ (my edits may take a little while to show). If not you should clarify. As for getting from (i) to (ii), simply expand the fourth powers out and add the results term by term (basically as one of the answers already suggests).

Answer (score 4):

What you need is the expansion of $(a+b)^4$. This is a special case of the very important [Binomial Theorem.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem) We have 
$$(a+b)^4=a^4+\binom{4}{1}a^3b+\binom{4}{2}a^2b^2+\binom{4}{3}ab^3+b^4.$$
This simplifies to $a^4+4a^3b+6a^2b^2+4ab^3+b^4$.

Put $a=y$, $b=1$, then $a=y$, $b=-1$, and add. There is a pleasant amount of cancellation.

**Remarks:** $1.$ The *symmetrizing* move $y=x+4$ is a  useful idea.

$2$. For reasons of familiarity, we change the name, and study $(x+1)^4+(x-1)^4$. This function is *symmetric* about $x=0$. Our function is not $16$ at $x=0$, and by symmetry there are just as many solutions of $(x+1)^4+(x-1)^4=16$ with $x\gt 0$ as there are with $x\lt 0$. So let's see how many there are with $x\gt 0$.

$3.$ The solution $x=1$ is obvious. It is reasonably clear that there are no solutions with $0\lt x\lt 1$. And past $x=1$, our function is increasing. So there is exactly one positive solution, and therefore altogether there are two solutions.

Answer (score 3):

$$(y-1)^4+(y+1)^4$$
$$=y^4-\binom 41y^3+\binom 42y^2-\binom 43y+1+(y^4+\binom 41y^3+\binom 42y^2+\binom 43y+1)$$
$$=2(y^4+6y^2+1)$$

Comment: no no my question is how was equation (i) converted to equation (ii) i am stuck there further i know how to do it please help me in that part

Comment: @Akash, do you know binomial theorem?

Answer (score 3):

$$
\begin{align}
(y−1)^4 +(y+1)^4  
&= \left(y^4 − \binom{4}{1}y^3 + \binom{4}{2}y^2 − \binom{4}{3}y + 1\right) \\
&+ \left(y^4 + \binom{4}{1}y^3 + \binom{4}{2}y^2 + \binom{4}{3}y + 1\right) \\
&=2(y^4 + 6y^2 + 1) 
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Our website supports [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for outputting better looking and more legible mathematics. Please try to edit your question using the MathJax capabilities. As it stands it is a bit hard to tell what you mean to write.

Comment: I have taken the liberty of composting your answer into $\LaTeX$. If you wish to see the source, right click on the equation above and choose "Show Math As > TeX Commands"

Answer (score 1):

Multiply: $(y-1)^4-(y+1)^4=(y^4-4y^3+6y^2-4y+1)+(y^4+4y^3+6y^2+4y+1)$. Add.